# ERROR in Must have a source file to refactor

Tags: angular, webpack, ngtools

Strange error with webpack compilation:

> ERROR in Must have a source file to refactor.

Looking at the source code I found this message in `./node_modules/@ngtools/refactor.js`:

```
...   
if (!sourceFile) {
  throw new Error('Must have a source file to refactor.');
}
```

The configuration of @ngtools webpack plugin is pretty straightforward:

```
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    use: '@ngtools/webpack',
  }
```

Comment: were you updated `@angular/cli` to 6 beta version, I started seeing this issue when I was using `ngIvy` with angular 6 rc

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to include `AngularCompilerPlugin` with correct `mainPath` configuration in `webpack.config.js`. At least that's what fixed this for me.

```
plugins: [
  /**
   * Angular's webpack plugin to compile typescript and AOT for templates
   **/
  new ngTools.AngularCompilerPlugin({
    tsConfigPath: path.join(CONTEXT_DIR, "tsconfig.json"),
    mainPath: path.join(CONTEXT_DIR, "src/main.ts")
  }),
...
]
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone in pain, attempting to find this solution; merely change:

```
new AngularCompilerPlugin({
      mainPath: 'src/main.ts',<----
      tsConfigPath: 'src/tsconfig.app.json',
      skipCodeGeneration: true
    }),
```

..to this:

```
new AngularCompilerPlugin({
      mainPath: 'main.ts',<----
      tsConfigPath: 'src/tsconfig.app.json',
      skipCodeGeneration: true
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this error while running "ng build --aot=true" on an angular library. The reason was the missing files in the build configuration in angular.json file. The project was generated as an angular application instead of a library. The build section in angular.json was pointing to src/main.ts and src/style.css but there were no such files in the project. I added missing files to resolve the issue. Alternatively configuration can be changed to a library project.

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/ui-common",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "main": "src/main.ts", //missing file
```